# get value from object in php

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I am calling google api service . in response it gave me that object which i use var_dump($response) to see the data but now i want to extract field from this object .  how can i get the value from mData array fields in php

```
object(my-api-object)[59]
  protected 'internal_gapi_mappings' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'consumptionState' => null
  public 'developerPayload' => string 'subs:my_sub' (length=17)
  public 'ktext' => string 'myinfo' (length=37)
  public 'pState' => null
  public 'pTimeMillis' => null
  protected 'mData' => 
    array (size=8)
      'sTMillis' => string '1474357111810' (length=13)
      'eTMillis' => string '1474443493335' (length=13)
      'autoR' => boolean false
      'priceCC' => string 'USD' (length=3)
      'priceAM' => string '50000' (length=9)
      'cC' => string 'US' (length=2)
      'pState' => int 1
      'cReason' => int 0
  protected 'processed' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Comment: which value do u want ?

Comment: You have an array of Object so you need to use `->` to access the desire data from array. So `$response->mData['your_index_here']`.

Comment: no its not working didnt get any data from @Frayne Konok  i think its something to do with this protected too .. i need this data from this field     my-api-object->internal_gapi_mappings->mData['sTMillis'];

Comment: no its not working didnt get any data from @Anant   i think its something to do with this protected too .. i need this data from this field     my-api-object->internal_gapi_mappings->mData['sTMillis'];

Comment: Hey everyone! If you take a look `mData` is a **Protected** property.

Comment: @Anant bro its not working not showing anything

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are right thats why havig problem

Comment: Where does this object come from? Do you create?

Comment: @RiggsFolly google provide :(

Comment: Does it have a GET method within the object

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible options. You can either change your object so that the property is public instead of protected and access it with

```
$response->mData
```

or you can add a method to access the property like

```
public function getMData()
{
   return $this->mData;
}
```

and get the data with

```
$response->getMData()
```

All these options require you can modify the response object. Is this possible?